# Receive a message struct type using GetMessage and then assign to another same struct

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, process

I have already sent the message to the desired thread through `PostThreadMessage` and in the parameter `lparam` I pass the memory addresss to the struct I want to send:

```
struct myStruct estructura;
PostThreadMessage( p->idHilo, WM_USER, 10 , (LPARAM)&estructura);
```

When I receive I do this:

```
struct estructura *e;
while(GetMessage( &mensaje, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER+2)){
    e  =  &mensaje.lParam;
    printf("%c\n",e->miCaracter);
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with the process tag? Are you doing this cross-process?

Answer (score 0):

`e = &mensaje.lParam` is wrong, it should be `e = (estructura*) mensaje.lParam;` but it is still not going to work reliably.

You cannot **post** a message to another thread with a pointer to something on the stack because the stack might be gone/changed when the other thread retrieves the message.

Instead you should use one of these alternatives:

- Create a window so you can use `SendMessage`
- Allocate the structure on the heap and let the other thread free it
- Make the struct a global

If the thread is in another process then you could create a named file mapping instead.

Comment: i have cheked e = (estructura*) mensaje.lParam; but it doesn't work in any case.

Comment: @Alber yes, because it's gone if you haven't taken steps to prevent it.  Which of the three possibilities listed by Anders should you use?  I would go with 'Allocate the structure on the heap and let the other thread free it'.